# Windows Store App how to delete text from file

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, storagefile

In a windows store app, how can I delete text from a file ? For example

If I have

```
StorageFile file = await roamingfolder.CreateFileAsync(filename,
    CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, temp);
```

How can i remove some text from this file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally read the text into a string, remove the text, and rewrite the file.

Answer (score 0):

Here I get a file then I put the content to a stringbuilder then do some string operations, finally put the string back to the file using DataWriter

```
public static async Task UpdateTextContent(string contentItemId)
        {
            var storageFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFolderAsync(TARGET_FOLDER);
            StorageFile sf = null;
            try
            {
                //get content of the file make sure that it exist
                sf = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(TARGET_FILE);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            if (sf != null)
            {
                var targettxtfile = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sf);


                var sbProcessedTextToWrite = new StringBuilder(targettxtfile);



                if (targettxtfile.IndexOf(contentItemId) >= 0)
                {
                    string startmarker = new StringBuilder("[").Append(contentItemId).Append("#start]").ToString();
                    string endmarker = new StringBuilder("[").Append(contentItemId).Append("#end]").ToString();

                    int start = sbProcessedTextToWrite.ToString().IndexOf(startmarker);
                    int end = sbProcessedTextToWrite.ToString().IndexOf(endmarker);

                    int slen = end + endmarker.Length - start; 

                    //compute position to remove
                    sbProcessedTextToWrite.Remove(start, slen);
                }

                using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await sf.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                {
                    using (IOutputStream outputStream = fileStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
                    {
                        using (DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter(outputStream))
                        {

                            dataWriter.WriteString(sbProcessedTextToWrite.ToString());                            

                            await dataWriter.StoreAsync();

                            // For the in-memory stream implementation we are using, the flushAsync call 
                            // is superfluous,but other types of streams may require it.
                            await dataWriter.FlushAsync();

                            // In order to prolong the lifetime of the stream, detach it from the 
                            // DataWriter so that it will not be closed when Dispose() is called on 
                            // dataWriter. Were we to fail to detach the stream, the call to 
                            // dataWriter.Dispose() would close the underlying stream, preventing 
                            // its subsequent use by the DataReader below.
                            dataWriter.DetachStream();
                        }

                        //same here flush the outputStream as well
                        await outputStream.FlushAsync();
                    }
                }
            }


        }
```

[Some references for this code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datawriter.aspx)